# Want to scrape a static url page website with pagination enabled

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from zenrows import ZenRowsClient
import uuid

base_url = 'https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com'
client = ZenRowsClient("")
url = "https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruiting/abinbev/USA"
response = client.get(url, params={"js_render": "true", "wait": 3000})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

jobs_listings = soup.find_all('li', class_='css-1q2dra3')

for jobs_listing in jobs_listings:
    try:
        job_title = jobs_listing.find('h3').find('a').text
        city_name = jobs_listing.find('dd', class_='css-129m7dg').text.strip()
        

        job_link = jobs_listing.find('h3').find('a')['href']
        date_posted_section = jobs_listing.find(
            'div', {'data-automation-id': 'postedOn'})
        date_posted = date_posted_section.find(
            'dd', class_='css-129m7dg').text.strip()
        if date_posted != 'Posted Yesterday':

            job_page_url = base_url + job_link
            job_page_response = client.get(
                job_page_url, params={"js_render": "true", "wait": 3000})
            job_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(job_page_response.content, 'html.parser')
            description_section = job_page_soup.find(
                'div', {'data-automation-id': 'jobPostingDescription', 'class': 'css-oplht1'})

            job = {
                "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
                "title": job_title,
                "job_location": city_name,
                "employment_type": employment_type,
                "description": str(description_section),
                
                }
```

This is my code to scrape this website https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruiting/abinbev/USA
I'm able to scrap first page but unable to scrape other pages.
As we see there is pagination in websites but when I'm navigating to page2,3 and so on `web_url` remains same so how can I scrape other pages data?

I don't want to use selenium in this case

I'm using zenrows,beautiful soap but unable to get from page2 onwards

Comment: I only see two jobs posted on that website anywhere, presented in a single page. Are you sure there are more pages?

Comment: @BoppreH i have updated the url
https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruiting/abinbev/USA

Answer (score 1):

The URL shown by the browser is the same, but the paged data is fetched by POST'ing to this URL: `https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/wday/cxs/abinbev/USA/jobs`.

The good news is that this makes your job a lot easier. You can send JSON data and receive JSON data, without HTML or BeautifulSoup. The only hard part was identifying when the last page was read, because the website loops back to sending repeating postings. So you have to keep track of the jobs seen, and stop when they repeat:

```
import requests

LIMIT = 20

all_job_postings = []
paths_seen = []

url = 'https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/wday/cxs/abinbev/USA/jobs'

offset = 0
while True:
    response = requests.post(url, json={"appliedFacets":{},"limit":LIMIT,"offset":offset,"searchText":""})
    job_postings = response.json()['jobPostings']

    # The only sign that we've processed all pages is that the jobs start repeating.
    new_paths = [posting['externalPath'] for posting in job_postings]
    if any(new_path in paths_seen for new_path in new_paths): break
    paths_seen.extend(new_paths)    

    all_job_postings.extend(job_postings)
    offset += len(job_postings)

print(len(all_job_postings))
# 155
```

Each job posting looks like this:

```
{'title': 'Director Retail Sales - On Premise', 'externalPath': '/job/St-Louis-Missouri/Director-Retail-Sales---On-Premise_30056661', 'locationsText': '3 Locations', 'postedOn': 'Posted Yesterday', 'bulletFields': ['30056661']}
```

You can then fetch details from the externalPath URL.